# Is it possible to add new file filter to Add Existing Item dialog in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have developed a VSPackage and created my own Project Sub type (which derives from C# project type).
In addition I have created an item template for a new file extension *.ext. Now I am trying to add a new filter called "My Files; *.ext" to the Add Existing Item Dialog in visual studio which will be available when working with projects of my project sub type. Is it possible?  I have tried to add a Filters entry in the registry under VisualStudio\Projects\ProjectSubTypeGuid with my filter name, but it doesn't works. How should I do this?

Thanks,
Marina

Answer (score 1):

There is a filter property on the FileDialog base class that you can set to limit the file extensions.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)